# ¿Porque no me va este endpoint en mongo? error:Jewel.aggregate(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb

He estado utlizando mongoose con js, y postman, he probado muchas consultas, la mayotia simples tipo find o set, pero este endpoint no me va. Postman funciona bien, la conexion a mongoose tambien, pero cuando intento hacer este agregate me sale este error:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "message": "Jewel.aggregate(...).then is not a function",
        "error": {}
    }
}

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
var slug = require('slug');

var JewelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  slug: { type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true },
  name: String,
  brand: String,
  type: String,
  price: Number,
  favoritesCount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
  commentsCount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  tagList: [{ type: String }],
  owner: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
}, { timestamps: true });


const Jewel = mongoose.model('jewel', JewelSchema)



JewelSchema.methods.updateComentsCount = function () {

  var jewel = this;
    return Jewel.aggregate([{"$match":{name:jewel._id}},{"$project": { count: { "$size":"$comments" }}}])
.then(function (count) {
 console.log(count)
    return count
  });
}
```

---

Hago esto :

```
JewelSchema.methods.updateComentsCount = function () {

  return Jewel.aggregate([{ "$match": { name: "Submarine" } }, { "$project": { count: { "$size": "$comments" } } }])
    .exec()
};

 req.jewel.updateComentsCount().then(function(count){
          console.log(count)
)}
```

Y no me devuelve nada se queda ahi, y postaman se queda en "Sending request...."

---

Hice lo que tu me dijiste pero intento recoger los datos de esta consulta, con lo siguiente

```
Jewel.aggregate([{ "$match": { _id: jewel._id } }, { "$project": { count: { "$size": "$comments" } } }])
  .exec(function(count){

console.log(count)
})
```

O tambien si hago lo siguiente pasa lo mismo:

```
return Jewel.aggregate([{ "$match": { _id: jewel._id } }, { "$project": { count: { "$size": "$comments" } } }])
  .exec()
```

Esto enseña la terminal, no sigue la respuesta

```
Mongoose: jewels.aggregate([ { '$match': { _id: 5f915fca3bc2b42349741c34 } }, { '$project': { count: { '$size': '$comments' } } } ]) {}
```

Y postman se queda en: "Sending request"

Comment: Revisa la edición a mi [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/400361/porque-no-me-va-este-endpoint-en-mongo-errorjewel-aggregate-then-is-not/400373#400373). Y por favor, no uses el espacio de respuestas para agregar información, puedes [edit] tu pregunta para agregar todo lo necesario. Saludos

Comment: Inspeccionando tu modelo de datos, tienes un campo llamado `commentsCount` de tipo `Number`. Imagino que lo que pretendes es actualizar dicho campo al momento de salvar (actualizar) un documento. ¿Podrías aclarar si esto es así? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar una consulta de agregación sobre una colección de datos de MongoDB, usando un Modelo de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com) y el método [`aggregate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate).

Sin embargo al hacer:

```js
Model.aggregate(aggr, options).then( ... );
```

Se obtiene el error mencionado.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es sencilla, simplemente debemos obtener la Promesa antes de intentar usarla. Y es que el método `aggregate()` no devuelve una Promesa (devuelve un Objeto `Aggregate`) a menos que pasemos una función `callback` como tercer argumento o a menos que usemos el método [`exec()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-exec) del objeto `Aggregate`.

Por lo tanto debes simplemente reescribir tu lógica de la siguiente manera:

```js
return Jewel.aggregate([{"$match":{name:jewel._id}},{"$project": { count: { "$size":"$comments" }}}]).exec();
```

Otro problema es que estás mezclando una sentencia `return` con el método `then` de una Promesa. Esa no es la forma de trabajar con Promesas o procesos asíncronos.

Cuando devuelves una Promesa, quien recibe la misma es la encargada de implementar `then`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const updateCount = MyJewelsInstance.updateComentsCount();
updateCount.then(handler);
```

Siendo tu método de instancia simplemente lo siguiente:

```js
JewelSchema.methods.updateComentsCount = function () {
  let jewel = this;
  return Jewel.aggregate([{"$match":{name:jewel._id}},{"$project": { count: { "$size":"$comments" }}}]).exec();
}
```

Por último, cuando trabajas con NodeJS, a menos que lo hagas en una versión muy antigua (inferior a 6.4), lo aconsejable es usar `let` y `const` en vez de `var`.

**Edición**

Un error que no me percaté que tienes, en el código de tu pregunta, es que estás declarando el método de instancia después de construir el modelo de datos. Dicho método no pertenecerá a la instancia de modelo, ya que fue declarado después de construir el mismo. Debes mover la declaración del modelo al final de tu código de esquema. Debería ser la última cosa que hagas. Por ejemplo:

```js
const MiSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // ... campos de Schema
});

// primero declaro mis metodos
MiSchema.methods.miMetodo = function() { ... }; // el método

// ahora si puedo declarar mi modelo
const MiModelo = mongoose.model('MiModelo', MiSchema);
```

Comment: Primero muchas gracias, si lo de el let y const si que lo se lo he empezado a utlizar hace unos meses, por otra parte como recojo los datos de este exec()?

Comment: Como te mencioné, bien sea usando un `callback` o mediante el uso de `then()` en la Promesa devuelta. La sentencia `return Jewel.aggregate.exec()` devuelve una Promesa. Puedes recibir la misma en una variable: `let updateCount = MyJewelsInstance.updateComentsCount();` y luego ejecutar el método `then()` sobre esa variable: `updateCount.then(result => { console.log(result) });`